# Why is sendKeys() not functioning properly in casperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, html-input, form-fields

I am writing an automation script to sign into draftkings.com.  I am using sendKeys() to add my login credentials to the required fields.  The first use of sendKeys() is for the username field which has the ID "Username". This will actually put my username into the field.  The second use is for the password field with the ID "Password". However, this puts the desired text for this field into the username field.  Am I missing something?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
loadImages:false,
verbose: true,
logLevel: 'debug'
});

//set browser user agent
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');

//Open URL
casper.start('https://draftkings.com');

casper.then(function() {
    this.clickLabel('Sign-in', 'a');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys('#Username', 'xxxx');
    this.sendKeys('#Password', 'xxxx');
    this.click('a[data-signin-submit="1"]');

});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('test67_failed.png');
});
casper.run();
```

**UPDATE:**

I was unable to figure out why `sendKeys` was not working properly.  I ended up just using `this.evaluate()` to enter the values into the fields with `document.querySelector()`.

**NEW ISSUE:**

I can see in the console output that `'a[data-signin-submit="1"]'` is being clicked and that the http request is being sent, but it is not actually logging me it.  I am using phantomJS 2.0.0 so it is not an ssl issue though I tried that already.  If my credentials were the capture would show that.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `casper.wait(5000, function(){/*capture*/});` after login.

Comment: Tried that. Not sure whats going on.  Going to keep digging into it

Comment: if you have it select submit with invalid credentials do you capture a red box that says "Password must contain at least one letter and one number, and be 5-20 characters long."  I cant so I think there is something wrong with the click() on the sign in button

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the input provided in  `this.click()` ,try entering xpath instead by using

```
this.click(x('your xpath here'));
```